# How to fix P2195, P1172, P1174 and P2197 error code for Honda Accord LX 2004?

Tags: honda, accord, air-fuel-ratio, code

**Make**: Honda

**Model**: Accord LX

**Year**: 2004

**Error codes**: P2195, P1172, P1174 and P219
Mile: The vehicle was driving for over 6 months

**Symptom**: there was a missing fuse for the A/F ratio sensor heaters. After the fuse was replaced, the PCM sets P2195, P1172, P1174 and P2197.

**Things that I have tried**: replaced a fuse for the A/F ratio sensor heater

**Knowledge level**: I know little about cars

What could be the cause of my issues?

Answer (score 7):

When you get a bunch of codes on a car, the best way to work through is to fix only the first code - in this case the P2195. The easiest check is to look for a disconnected cable - Rear A/F Sensor Sensor 1 Bank 1 (which is also a cause of P1172). If everything checks out good, the other cause of a P2195 points towards the MAF having some debris in it.

From http://www.autocodes.com/p2195_honda.html;

Debris in the MAF sensor can also set this P2195 code.

1. Remove the MAF sensor, and check for debris (lint, bugs, foreign objects, etc.).
2. Open the air cleaner housing cover, remove the air cleaner element, and check it for damage.
   A damaged air cleaner element lets debris get into the MAF sensor. Replace the air cleaner element if needed.
3. Clean out the air cleaner housing. To keep from contaminating the MAF sensor, don’t use compressed air; use a vacuum instead.
4. Reinstall the air cleaner element, the housing cover, and the MAF sensor.
5. Clear the DTC.

Once you've checked this, clear all codes (using a cheap OBDII reader) and go through a drive cycle; see what codes come back, and tackle the first one in the list.

Comment: I'd add that it's at least good to look up all the codes to see how they might be related, but just know that might not give you a smoking gun.

Comment: IIRC the Honda 3.0 doesn't use a MAF sensor. The 2.4 SULEV does, but only has 1 AFR sensor.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest you need to be able to view live data using a scan tool. If you don't have access to these it may be cheaper to take it to a shop that specializes in Hondas.

It's not inconceivable that both AFR sensors failed at the same time, but unlikely. Don't replace potentially expensive AFR sensors without doing basic checks first.

[image]

- Check for vacuum leaks (using something like starting fluid).
- Check signal return voltage at the AFR sensor connector while introducing a vacuum leak or adding propane. If the sensor is
  functioning correctly and all wiring is OK the sensor should quickly
  respond to changes.
- Check sensor heater resistance (0.8Ω - 2.0Ω) at operating temperature.
- Inspect the wiring harness for damage.